# Question about the Cauchy Product and how it is done

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series, cauchy-product

Lets say we have the following:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!(k-j)!} B_{k-j}^f(x) \frac{d^{j}}{dx^{j}}[a_k(x)]
$$

Would it be correct to say that:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!(k-j)!} B_{k-j}^f(x) \frac{d^{j}}{dx^{j}}[a_k(x)] = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dx^k}[a_k(x)]\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!} B_k^f(x)\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't correct.  Not unless $a_k(x)$ is independent of the variable of summation, k.

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k = (\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k)( \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k)$$

Then

$$c_k = \sum^k_{j=0} a_{k-j}b_{j} $$

In your case...

$$\sum^k_{j=0} \frac{1}{j!(k-j!)}B^f_{k-j}(x)\frac{d^j}{dx^j}[a_k(x)]z^k = \sum^k_{j=0} (\frac{B^f_{k-j}(x)z^{k-j}}{(k-j!)})(\frac{z^j}{j!}\frac{d^j}{dx^j}[a_k(x)])$$

This implies that

$$\frac{B^f_{k-j}(x)z^{k-j}}{(k-j)!} = a_{k-j}$$
$$\frac{z^j}{j!}\frac{d^j}{dx^j}[a_k(x)] = b_j$$

But, as you can see in the $b_j$ expression, there is still $a_k(x)$, not $a_j(x)$

Comment: Is there any way to split up this summation?

Comment: Not that I can think of.  Perhaps when you put it together, the annotation was a mistake?  I don't know.